# Grouping custom tool parts in with other custom properties

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a webpart. I have a list of items (schools) that I must pick from. This list comes from another Sharepoint list. I made a tool part. This tool part creates a drop down list and populates it with the correct data. When I went to edit the web part properties, the drop down list is sitting outside of any other group. I want to add that drop down list into the "Miscellaneous" group. If I can't put it there, I want to create a custom group.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To add other groups, you will need some client manipulations (jquery).

Or you can just create extra groups:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls() {
 Panel panel = new Panel();
 panel.CssClass = "ms-ToolPartSpacing";
 Table table = new Table();
 table.CellPadding = 0;
 table.CellSpacing = 0;
 table.Style["border-collapse"] = "collapse";
 table.Attributes.Add("width", "100%");
 TableRow row = new TableRow();
 TableCell cell = new TableCell();
 cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"UserSectionHead\"><b>Your Other Group:</b></div>"));
 cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"UserSectionBody\"><div class=\"UserControlGroup\">"));
 Table innertable = new Table();
 //build your innertable
 cell.Controls.Add(innertable);
 cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div></div>"));
 cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style='width:100%' class='UserDottedLine'></div>"));
 row.Cells.Add(cell);
 table.Rows.Add(row);
 panel.Controls.Add(table);
 this.Controls.Add(panel);
 base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

Comment: No way to do this on the server side?